# Imagens somem depois do build

Tags: imagem, ionic3

Estou desenvolvendo um APP no Ionic 3, coloquei as imagens no diretório **assets/img/imagem.png** e quando rodo o Ionic Server no laboratório, aparecem normalmente, porém quando faço o build e instalo o APK, todas as imagens somem ou seja, não aparecem no emulador e nem no aparelho.

Comment: Já tentou colocar o caminho relativo, desta forma?: "./assets/img/imagem.png" ou então "../assets/img/imagem.png", tudo depende da estrutura do seu projeto entendeu?

Comment: Já sim no ionic lab elas funcionam normalmente, o problema e só quando gera o apk, ou seja depois da build ../../assets/img/imagem.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é o relative path.

Assim funciona no emulador:

```
<img src="../assets/img/teste.png">
```

Assim deve trabalhar no aparelho:

```
<img src="assets/img/teste.png">
```

Comment: Meu Amigo funcionou muito obrigado